# How to find and add bold a string in a paragraph?

Tags: php, html, search, replace

I have being creating a Search Script for my site. But I wanna `italic` the matched words in the Description of every search result. The script I'm using is in `PHP` and the Description paragraph has variable `$search_desc`. Currently I'm using `str_ireplace()` function to achieve my goal. **But I think my goal is too far away**! Here is the function

```
echo str_ireplace($search_query,"<i>".$search_query."</i>",$search_desc);
```

But the problem is that if the search query is `search` and for the example the Description of a search result is,

> This is description for Search Demo.

So the Description after adding `italic` property to the matched word it shows

> This is description for search Demo.

So you can see the problem is big. Because the original Description gets edited! So anyone have got any ideas for my problem? Please if you do let me know!

Comment: For highlighting search results in a HTML aware manner, a related question is: [Ignore html tags in preg_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8193327/367456)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want to use is preg_replace.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

This function allows you to search and replace using a token for the word that was found.  Something like this might work:

```
$string = "This is description for Search Demo";
$searchingFor = "/" . $searchQuery . "/i";
$replacePattern = "<i>$0<\/i>";
preg_replace($searchingFor, $replacePattern, $string);
```

This code might have errors, I just threw it together quickly.  But I think this is the right idea for your situation.

Comment: It's a good solution. Only have errors when slashes are used.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can easily achieve your goal using javascript. Try this:

1) Include the following code:

```
<style>
<!-- 
    SPAN.searchword { font-style:italic; }
    // -->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

function stripVowelAccent(str)
{
    var rExps=[ /[\xC0-\xC2]/g, /[\xE0-\xE2]/g,
        /[\xC8-\xCA]/g, /[\xE8-\xEB]/g,
        /[\xCC-\xCE]/g, /[\xEC-\xEE]/g,
        /[\xD2-\xD4]/g, /[\xF2-\xF4]/g,
        /[\xD9-\xDB]/g, /[\xF9-\xFB]/g ];

    var repChar=['A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u'];

    for(var i=0; i<rExps.length; ++i)
        str=str.replace(rExps[i],repChar[i]);

    return str;
}

/* Modification of */
/* http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/searchhi/ */
/* See: */
/*   http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_highlighting_search_results_with_ted_searchhi_javascript.php */    
/*   http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_inpage_highlighting_example.php */
/* for additional modifications of this base code. */
function highlightWord(node,word,doc) {
     doc = typeof(doc) != 'undefined' ? doc : document;
    // Iterate into this nodes childNodes
    if (node.hasChildNodes) {
        var hi_cn;
        for (hi_cn=0;hi_cn<node.childNodes.length;hi_cn++) {
            highlightWord(node.childNodes[hi_cn],word,doc);
        }
    }

    // And do this node itself
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text node
        tempNodeVal = stripVowelAccent(node.nodeValue.toLowerCase());
        tempWordVal = stripVowelAccent(word.toLowerCase());
        if (tempNodeVal.indexOf(tempWordVal) != -1) {
            pn = node.parentNode;
            if (pn.className != "searchword") {
                // word has not already been highlighted!
                nv = node.nodeValue;
                ni = tempNodeVal.indexOf(tempWordVal);
                // Create a load of replacement nodes
                before = doc.createTextNode(nv.substr(0,ni));
                docWordVal = nv.substr(ni,word.length);
                after = doc.createTextNode(nv.substr(ni+word.length));
                hiwordtext = doc.createTextNode(docWordVal);
                hiword = doc.createElement("span");
                hiword.className = "searchword";
                hiword.appendChild(hiwordtext);
                pn.insertBefore(before,node);
                pn.insertBefore(hiword,node);
                pn.insertBefore(after,node);
                pn.removeChild(node);
            }
        }
    }
}

function unhighlight(node) {
    // Iterate into this nodes childNodes
    if (node.hasChildNodes) {
        var hi_cn;
        for (hi_cn=0;hi_cn<node.childNodes.length;hi_cn++) {
            unhighlight(node.childNodes[hi_cn]);
        }
    }

    // And do this node itself
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text node
        pn = node.parentNode;
        if( pn.className == "searchword" ) {
            prevSib = pn.previousSibling;
            nextSib = pn.nextSibling;
            nextSib.nodeValue = prevSib.nodeValue + node.nodeValue + nextSib.nodeValue;
            prevSib.nodeValue = '';
            node.nodeValue = '';
        }
    }
}

function localSearchHighlight(searchStr,doc) {
     doc = typeof(doc) != 'undefined' ? doc : document;
    if (!doc.createElement) return;
        if (searchStr == '') return;
    // Trim leading and trailing spaces after unescaping
    searchstr = unescape(searchStr).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if( searchStr == '' ) return;
    phrases = searchStr.replace(/\+/g,' ').split(/\"/);
    // Use this next line if you would like to force the script to always
    // search for phrases. See below as well!!!
    //phrases = new Array(); phrases[0] = ''; phrases[1] = searchStr.replace(/\+/g,' ');
    for(p=0;p<phrases.length;p++) {
            phrases[p] = unescape(phrases[p]).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if( phrases[p] == '' ) continue;
        if( p % 2 == 0 ) words = phrases[p].replace(/([+,()]|%(29|28)|\W+(AND|OR)\W+)/g,' ').split(/\s+/);
        else { words=Array(1); words[0] = phrases[p]; }
                for (w=0;w<words.length;w++) {
            if( words[w] == '' ) continue;
            highlightWord(doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],words[w],doc);
            }
    }
}

</script>
```

2) Call the function

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onload=localSearchHighlight('search search');
</script>
```

[Source](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_simple_inpage_highlighting_example.php)

Comment: Thanks buddy, but I want it to be a PHP code. But anyways I will use it later, that's why I'm voting it up too!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "<p>Helllow world this is a string</p>";
str_replace('world','<b>world</b>',$string);
```

Try This example it will work fine

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe how your answer is related to the question, please? Thanks.

Comment: Hi.  I am new on SO. please guide me. what you want.& what can I do for you? ;) Thanks